# Notifydatasetchanged() between adapters

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have 2 recycleviews and both of them have a number of icons. I also have a list that contains a number, which is the number that represents which icon has a background that shows it has been clicked.

Now, the problem is that I only want one icon marked, with this I mean 1 item in total of those 2 recyclewviews. The way I've tried to do this is having a json that saves a number that determines which recycleview should have a marked item, if it doesn't have the number of the recycleview, then the background is the normal one, that way only one recycleview has a marked item.

The problem is that for that to work I need to call the method Notifydataserchanged() on the other adapter so the marked background dissappears, and the easiest way of doing that is putting the other adapter on the constructor. The problem with this is that only works for one, because since the other is declared before you can't construct it with the adapter that comes after it.

I've seen way of doing it with listeners/interfaces made in the activity and then
moved to the adapter itself so you can just call those methods, but it hasn't worked for me.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050210/what-is-the-difference-between-swapadapter-method-and-notifydatasetchanged-metho)?

Comment: It doesn't help me because I need a way of communicating both adapters, that would work as the Notifydatasetchanged.